# Xamarin resets Detail Property of MasterDetailPage/FlyoutPage when power saving mode is turned on

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation

I have a weird problem with my Xamarin App. When I turn on the power saving mode the App resets the Detail Property of my MasterDetailPage and thus navigate back to the Loginscreen. I cant really debug that.
My Navigation works like that: I create a new NavigationPage and set the Detail Property of my MasterDetailPage to the new NavigationPage.

Does anyone know why this happens?

//Edit using FlyoutPage instead of MasterDetailPage doesn't work

//Edit2 apparently that only happens on my Zebra TC26. Also it not only resets the Detail property to its default value it resets ALL variables/properties in my entire app except static ones to its default value...

Comment: Have you tested it on other device? Also it would be helpful if you put your code in the question.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT apparently that only happens on my Zebra TC26. Also it not only resets the Detail property to its default value it resets ALL variables/properties in my entire app except static ones to its default value...